# Python list comprehensions and order of conditions

Tags: python-2.7

Is there a difference between the following list comprehensions:

1.

```
f = [(x,y) for x in a if x > 0 for y in b]

print f
```

2.

```
f = [(x,y) for x in a for y in b if x > 0]

print f
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no, long answer slightly.

When you write something like the following:

```
f = [(x,y) for x in range(a) if x > 0 for y in range(b)]
```

Then you can rewrite it as the following which I will call p1:

```
for x in range(a):
    if (x > 0):
        for y in range(b):
            f.append((x, y))
print f
```

And when you write something like the following:

```
f = [(x,y) for x in range(a) for y in range(b) if x > 0]
```

Then you can rewrite it as the following which I will call p2:

```
for x in range(a):
    for y in range(b):
        if (x > 0):
            f.append((x,y ))
print f
```

I rewrote them like this because it's easier to comprehend.

I should note that I can't recommend using for loops inside for loops as it gets harder to cope with the code, only use this when you really have to.

In p1 it will check whether or not x > 0 before running through the next for loop.

This has the advantage that you don't even have to run through the rest of the process if x > 0 and thus time is saved. It will not check the new value of y since you are telling it that it's unnecessary.

p2 has to run through both for loops before deciding whether or not x > 0. This is not as effective as p1.

The key difference is that p1 should be more effective than p2 because it saves time. In the end they both give the same result.

What is happening in p1 is called short-circuiting. This is not a bad thing like in electronics though. Short-circuiting just means that you do a boolean check to see whether or not it's necessary to evaluate the rest of a statement.

Let us say that we have to boolean values, x and y. x is set to false while y is set to true. We can evaluate the following statement:

```
if x && y:
    print 'Hello World!'
```

The &&(and) operator first checks whether or not x is true or false. If x is false there is no reason to continue as the && operator requires both statements to be true. We short-circuit here so y is not evaluated and the print function is not run either.

Let us use the same boolean values again. We can evaluate the following statement:

```
if y || x:
    print 'Hello World!'
```

Since y is evaluated as true, it won't evaluate x. The || operator only needs one true boolean statement and since y is true it won't evaluate x.

This has the nice property that we can 'hide' statements on the right side of the operators. It's great when the right statement is something that can crash the program such as sqrt(-1) where -1 is a user input.

If you want to read more about short-circuit evaluations then you can read some more on [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)